# docker base image change lead to maven not work well

Tags: java, maven, docker

we are using gitlab as our CI/CD tool, always using the `image:atlassianlabs/docker-node-jdk-chrome-firefox:2018-04-23`,
but about one month ago, suddenly every sonar jobs are all down. AND we changed nothing.

Even if now, while using `mvn clean install` command erverything still goes well
but using `mvn sonar:sonar` NPE happened.
I tried to change to run the scripts in local docker environment, but everything goes ok.

```
image: atlassianlabs/docker-node-jdk-chrome-firefox:2018-04-23
stages：
 - sonar
sonar-check:
 stage: sonar
script:
 mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN -Dsonar.branch=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

and error output is

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:12 min (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-22T06:51:32+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 121M/3392M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder.multiThreadedProjectTaskSegmentBuild(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder.build(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder.multiThreadedProjectTaskSegmentBuild(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:166)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't know what happened there, but after a couple of result outputs comparing, an interesting thing came up, the success version runs in 
`OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-1047-aws", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"` and the failed  ones are run in

```
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-1066-aws", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Could anybody help to point me a right direction to find out what caused this?
All tools versions are here

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_162, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-1010-aws", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: The base image of ```atlassianlabs/docker-node-jdk-chrome-firefox:2018-04-23``` is using ```buildpack-deps:jessie-scm```

Comment: resolved by using ```maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-alpine``` image instead. after that install node manually, it works.